# Javafx,TranslateTransition, animation

Tags: java, animation, javafx-2

I want to create some Shapes with JavaFx and I want that every shape has his own TranslateTransition object defined within it, and I want that when I click on the shape the TranslateTransition play. my code:

the shape class :

```
package com;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.util.Duration;

public class MShape  extends Parent{
private TranslateTransition Transition;
Circle circle;
DoubleProperty tox;
DoubleProperty toy;
public MShape(int i, int j) {
    circle = new Circle(20);
    circle.setCenterX(i);
    circle.setCenterY(j);
    circle.setFill(Color.RED);
    Transition= new TranslateTransition();
    Transition.setToX(350);
    Transition.setToX(375);
    Transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(2));
    Transition.setNode(this.circle);
    this.getChildren().add(circle);
    circle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<Event>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(Event paramT) {
            Transition.play();
            System.out.println("hello");
        }
    });


}

}
```

the main class

```
package com;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application{

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    VBox root = new VBox();
    stage.setScene(new Scene(root,800,600));

    MShape test =new MShape(100, 100);
    root.getChildren().add(test);
    stage.show();
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
launch(args);
}


}
```

the problem that when I press on the shape it doesn't move

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't extend `Parent`.

this works for me:

```
public class Test extends Application {
    private Circle circle;
    private TranslateTransition transition;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        /**
         * MShape
         */
        circle = new Circle(20);
        circle.setCenterX(100);
        circle.setCenterY(100);
        circle.setFill(Color.RED);


        transition = new TranslateTransition();
        transition.setToX(500);
        transition.setToX(500);

        transition.setDuration(Duration.seconds(5));
        transition.setNode(this.circle);

//      this.getChildren().add(circle);

        circle.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent paramT) {
                transition.play();
                System.out.println("hello  " + circle.getCenterX() + "  " + circle.getCenterY());

            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 800, 600);
        stage.setScene(scene);

        root.getChildren().add(circle);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you tarrsalah 
I solve my problem by doing this 
transition.node(this);
instead of transition.node(this.circle);